# Redux - selectors not accessing state

Tags: redux, reselect

I've started learning selectors and redux. The state of the app looks as follows:

[image: State unfolded]

And then unfolded:

[image]

I'm trying to add a selector that would count the total of the sub-array first elements eg(6 + 4 + ..., etc), but first things first:

I've started writing a selector (for now just to display anything):

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const getValues = (state) => state.grid;

export const getSelected = createSelector(
  [getValues],
  grid => grid[0]
);
```

Then a container has:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  score: state.score,
  grid: state.grid,
  values: getSelected(state.grid)
});
```

But I get an error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

The whole code can be seen here:
https://github.com/wastelandtime/memgame

Please advise. Thank you

Comment: you have passed `state.grid` to `getSelected` instead of `state`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing wrong value to your selector. Change `values: getSelected(state.grid)` to `values: getSelected(state)` in your `mapStateToProps`.